# Remove data from Firebase with Ionic 3

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I want to remove a data from firebase but all documents I have found all said use .remove() function as I show as codesnippet here. But this is not work at Ionic 3. Is that function is changed or what is the point that I didn't see.

```
selectBook(indexOfBook : Book){

    this.actionSheetCtrl.create({
        title: indexOfBook.nameOfBook,
        buttons:[{
               text:'Edit',
               handler: () =>{
                   // TODO:Send the user to EditPage
               }

        },
        {
             text:'Delete',
             role: 'destructive',
             handler: () => {
                 this.getBookRef$.remove(indexOfBook.key);//**************************************
             }
        },
        {
            text:'Cancel',
            role:'cancel',
            handler: () =>{
                   console.log("The user has selected the cancel button");
            }
        }


        ]


    }).present();

}
```

Comment: show this.getBookRef$ property and the class or service you defined to the hit API Firebase

Comment: @Yoarthur [https://gist.github.com/alhnkyhn/](https://gist.github.com/alhnkyhn/cfe96f8e9d19a4a164221ee4582c7d1d)

Added full codes to this link

Comment: did you receive the data from firebase?

Comment: Try ` this.databse.list(`Books/${indexOfBook.key}`).remove();`

Comment: @Swoox  I took error 



 `Error: Reference.child failed: First argument was an invalid path = "Books/${indexOfBook.key}". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"`

Comment: @Yoarthur Yes i did.